# Serving webpack-built app without webpack-dev-server

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to serve a TypeScript app from webpack, yet **without** webpack-dev-server. The reason is that I want to see the bundle file created rather than have the app served from memory.
Below is my webpack.config.js. Should this setup be sufficient to serve the files?
(I have mutually exclude `hot: true` and `HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` as they are said not to play well together.)

**webpack.config.js**

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
         //'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888',
         //'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        './app.ts'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    ],

    devServer: {
        port: 8888,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Comment: Where did you end up with this?